# Why doesn't GNU `su` respect end of options?

Tags: su, gnu

When I run

```
user@hostname:~$ su -- root -z
```

I get

```
bash: -z: invalid option
Usage:  bash [GNU long option] [option] ...
...
```

The above is the behavior I expect.

When I run

```
user@hostname:~$ su -l -- root -z
```

I get

```
-su: -z: invalid option
Usage:  -su [GNU long option] [option] ...
...
```

I use the invalid option `-z` only to demonstrate which command is parsing the option.

This behavior irks me to no end. `su` continued searching for options after I declared end of options. Am I missing something, is this a bug or just horrible design?

Comment: `-z` is not an option for `su` or `bash`. It is intentional. I used a fake option to demonstrate which command was parsing the fake option I gave it.

Comment: Was `sudo su` supposed to demonstrate something in particular? Ref @Christopher's question

Comment: @Seamus No I was using `sudo` for debugging so I wouldn't have to enter a password for `root` every time I tested it. I tested without `sudo` and the behavior is the same. I can see how it completely diluted the question and made it confusing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> -su: -z: invalid option
> Usage:  -su [GNU long option] [option] ...
> ...
> ```

This is the error output from Bash, not from su. If you'd continued to quote, the very next line mentions a script file, for example, and later on the `--rcfile` option, which clearly doesn't belong to `su`. You could also compare to the output of `su -z`, which will be a *different* error.

If you run

```
su -l -- root --version
```

you'll see that the argument is passed along and it's Bash that reports its version.

Bash is reporting itself as `-su` (note the `-`) because that's what is in its zeroth argument when `su` invokes it as a login shell, not because it is `su` itself (or even `-su`).

---

Note that the `su` manual does actually state that:

> You can use the `--` argument to separate su options from the arguments
>   supplied to the shell.

which is what is happening here: the argument is passed along to the shell. If you'd left the `--` out, you'd get the `su` error output

```
su: invalid option -- 'z'
Usage: su [options] [LOGIN]
...
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to point out my silly mistake. When I run `su -- root -`, `bash` complains it cannot set the the terminal process group. Shouldn't `bash`just treat the `-` as end of options and start up the shell like the `-` isn't there?

Comment: If you provide shell arguments `su` doesn't give it a controlling TTY (try `su -- root -x`). I don't quite understand that choice, but it is consistent with `su -c 'bash'` so I suppose that's part of it.

Comment: I just don't understand why bash is freaking out about `-`. If i run `bash -` it starts a normal shell and treats the `-` as end of options. I guess I don't understand how a TTY even comes into play if all I'm doing to doing is telling bash that I'm done declaring options.